# request next page but url with no page numbers

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to scrape a url and get all links from 100 pages. The problem is that the url doesn't change to be formated with page number. I am able to get the first 10 links but I didn't find a way to get the links from page 2 till page 100.
Is there any way to do so without page number ? or filter 100 results per page? I am using python requests and beautifulsoup

my code so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

project = []

url = 'https://unicorner.news'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

links = []
categories = soup.findAll('a','utils_postLink__m_2J6')
for category in categories:
    links.append(category['href'])
```

how to continue?

Comment: You probably need to use selenium for this. To me it looks like the articles are updated with Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly access the article data by calling the website's data API.

Try this:

```
url = "https://unicorner.news/_next/data/XpX_u4UJUUahh9Sa-aCE4"
res = requests.get(url)
data = res.content
df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(data)["pageProps"]["articles"])
df.head()
```

Print out:

```
image   oneliner    name    date    url     description
0   https://img.mailinblue.com/2970250/images/rnb/...   Automate repetitive tasks with one click    Bardeen     July 25, 2022   https://sh1.sendinblue.com/3g6fxt972pxpfe.html...   Bardeen is a no-code workflow automation tool....
1   https://img.mailinblue.com/2970250/images/rnb/...   Bringing commands and search to any app     CommandBar  July 18, 2022   https://sh1.sendinblue.com/3g63ap972pxpfe.html...   CommandBar is a search bar that enables users ...
2   https://img.mailinblue.com/2970250/images/rnb/...   Automate copy-and-pasting between tabs  Magical     July 11, 2022   https://sh1.sendinblue.com/3g5z2zx72pxpfe.html...   Magical allows you to quickly transfer data be...
3   https://img.mailinblue.com/2970250/images/rnb/...   Advertising without cookies     SegmentStream   July 4, 2022    https://sh1.sendinblue.com/3g5uval72pxpfe.html...   SegmentStream provides businesses marketing an...
4   https://img.mailinblue.com/2970250/images/rnb/...   YouTube creator school  creator now     June 27, 2022   https://sh1.sendinblue.com/3g5qnl972pxpfe.html...   creator now is an online learning platform and...
```

If you just want the links do this:

```
df.url.values
```

Print out:

```
array(['https://sh1.sendinblue.com/3g6fxt972pxpfe.html?t=1658778042',
       'https://sh1.sendinblue.com/3g63ap972pxpfe.html?t=1658167180',
       'https://sh1.sendinblue.com/3g5z2zx72pxpfe.html?t=1657713951',
       'https://sh1.sendinblue.com/3g5uval72pxpfe.html?t=1657178365',
```

...

Comment: thanks alot! For next time, how can I find the api?

Comment: You're welcome! Open the website in Chrome, open the developer tools with right-click «Inspect», go to the tab «Network» and reload the webpage. You now see all calls the website makes to the backend. To filter for data requests you can further filter by choosing the «XHR» tab on the right side of the tool panel. I could see, that the data for the articles get called individually. However, the base of the URLs were all the same, so I tried to just call that and got the proper response. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank again. you saved the day